# Can we always find some integer $a$ such that $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{y}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This question arose on my head while solving another problem. Say we have have two positive integers $x,y$ such that they are coprime. Can we always find some integer $a$ such that $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{y}$? Furthermore, would it be unique or would we be able to find infinite such $a$?

Comment: Yes, this is immediate from the Euclidean algorithm.  And $a$ is of course not unique, but is unique mod $y$.

Comment: @Peter  I cited this other post a minute ago, but I retracted it because I don't think it's really a good duplicate.  It really only seems to address the (simpler) question of why an inverse *doesn't* exist when $\gcd(x,y)>1$.  There must be a better duplicate somewhere...

Comment: @Randall what do you mean by "is unique mod y"? Do you mean given an unique y, we can find a unique a?

Comment: No, any two suitable $a$s will be congruent mod $y$.

Comment: @Randall then what do you mean by "but is unique mod y"

Comment: I just said it.

Comment: Note the $a$ can also be expressed in function of $x,y$ by Euler theorem $a=x^{\varphi(y)-1}$, though much more complicated than Bezout as a justification.

Comment: @zwim that result is interesting. Can I get to know how you derived it

Answer (score -1):

Yes! If $x$ and $y$ are coprime, Bezout's theorem ensures that there exists $a,b$ such that $xa + yb = 1$.

It follows that $xa = 1 (\text{mod } y)$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).